# JAXB Unmarshalling resulted in SAXParser Exception

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I tried to unmarshall the xml resulted in saxparser exception because the value of a element has a tag element which is not properly closed. It is what I get and have to process.

Here is the sample xml -

```
<GetResultResponse>
  <ExecutionID>17716868</ExecutionID>
  <Device>STLMJWB</Device>
  <Status>Success</Status>
  <ResultSet>
    <Command>RTRV-ALM-ALL:STLMJWB0201000003FIS:ALL:<ctag=dq>;</Command>
    <CommandType>Raw</CommandType>
    <commandResult>Success</commandResult>
  <ResultSet>
</GetResultResponse>
```

The above xml contains  along with other string as value of command and the tag is not properly closed resulting in the following exception -

[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 212; Element type "ctag" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".]

The xml input to unmarshall is fed as string reader

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("ABOVE XML");
unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
```

I have two classes - One for GetResultResponse and other for ResultSet.

Things I tried to sort out - 
1. CharacterEscapeHandler - Got error when I assigned this proerpty to Unmarshaller because only marshaller accepts this.
2. XmlJavaTypeAdapter - Unmarshalling happens before processing and returning values from Adapter.
3. BeforeUnmarshall - Set listener to unmarshaller; Returns null for command.
4. XmlMixed and XmlAnyElement - Expects proper closing tag.

Pleae let me know if you have any doubts.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your XML as it currently is, is not valid.  You need to properly escape the text content here:

```
<Command>RTRV-ALM-ALL:STLMJWB0201000003FIS:ALL:<ctag=dq>;</Command>
```

As

```
<Command>RTRV-ALM-ALL:STLMJWB0201000003FIS:ALL:&lt;ctag=dq>;</Command>
```

Comment: Blaise, You are right. The data input xml is from other system which sends with tags [<ctag=dq>]. So, Is there any option to escape the text content before unmarshalling to avoid parse exception.                                                     Note : If I change the input xml with &lt;, I was able to properly unmarshall it to the respective object.                                                              Thanks